# How to catch click in all child elements?

Tags: jquery

Question is simple, but i can't do that... Here my code:

```
jQuery('nav').on('click', 'a',  function(event){
    console.log(jQuery(this));
});
```

Comment: @bipen there is only long `ul` and `li` list

Answer (score 1):

`nav` must be a class or Id , a nav does not seem to be a standard tag

if its a class name

```
jQuery('.nav').on('click', 'a',  function(event){
    console.log(jQuery(this));
});
```

if its an Id

```
jQuery('#nav').on('click', 'a',  function(event){
    console.log(jQuery(this));
});
```

Here there is live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/netme/hx8HR/

Comment: html5 has element `nav` which i use

Answer (score 1):

your codes looks fine.... but i think your are missing the `document.ready` function

try this

```
jQuery(function(){  //ready function
  jQuery('nav').on('click', 'a',  function(event){
    console.log(jQuery(this));
  });
});
```